# How to save the output of printf() as a variable in c?

Tags: c, variables, visual-studio-code, output

I've code c for a very short time and have a problem, which I can't solve.
I want to save a string with variables

```
"order_%d: <a href=\"order_%d\"><button>ON</button></a><br />", x, x    //x = 1,2,3,4...
```

into a variable named content. But all my attempts were useless. The code, which fits the most to my planned result is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
bool order_state = false;

int orders_cond (int x, bool state){
    if (!state){
        printf("order_%d: <a href=\"order_%d\"><button>ON</button></a><br />", x, x);
    }
    else {
        printf("Error");
    }
}
int main(){ 
    int x;
    printf("Enter a number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    orders_cond(x, order_state);
    return (0);
}
```

The output of this code is:

```
Enter a number:
8
order_8: <a href="order_8"><button>ON</button></a><br />
```

My idea was to save the last line of the output into a variable, but I don't know, how to do that.

Please explain me, how I can do this or if there's another method, how does this method work.

Comment: Use `sprintf()`?

Comment: ... or `snprintf`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `sprintf` to print the formatted string to your variable, then use `printf` to print the contents to the screen:

```
char contents[STRING_LEN] = {0};
sprintf(contents, "order_%d: <a href=\"order_%d\"><button>ON</button></a><br />", x, x);
printf("%s", contents);
```

The `sprintf` statement puts the formatted string into array `contents` and `printf` prints the contents of `contents` to the screen.

You will have to make sure that the array `contents` is large enough to hold the entire string, otherwise you will have overflow.

If you want to avoid overflow, you could use `snprintf` and replace the `sprintf` statement with:

```
snprintf(contents, STRING_LEN, "order_%d: <a href=\"order_%d\"><button>ON</button></a><br />", x, x);
```

An example may be found here:
https://www.educative.io/edpresso/storing-formatted-data-using-sprintf-in-c

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks.  I wasn't sure about that so was playing it safe, but it looks like you are right.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool order_state = false;

int orders_cond(int x, bool state, char *outputstring) {
  if (!state) {
    sprintf(outputstring, "order_%d: <a href=\"order_%d\"><button>ON</button></a><br />", x, x);
  }
  else {
    sprintf(outputstring, "Error");
  }

  return 0;   // you probably need to return something meaningful here
              // or have   void orders_cond(...
}

int main() {
  int x;
  printf("Enter a number:\n");
  scanf("%d", &x);

  char outputstring[100];
  orders_cond(x, order_state, outputstring);

  printf("Content of outputstring: \"%s\"\n", outputstring);

  return 0;   // Bonus: don't put expressions after return between (), it's unusual and useless.
}
```

Disclaimer: there is still room for improvement, for example by using `snprintf` in order to prevent buffer overflows.